# Sharing PropertyChanged data among different viewmodels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

[MyproblemDescription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JHMH.png)

In the above image as you can see 
ViewModelA has a property IsPopupOpen. On change (value) of that property I want ViewModelB and ViewModelC should get notified.

Now ViewmodelB and ViewModelC has property IsUserCtlVisible (bool).
Now I want if IsPopupOpen property changes(of ViewModelA) then IsUserCtlVisible property should get the value from ViewModelA and get the value.
Plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some options:
1.use prism and then in that case use publish and subscribe method to fire an event and subscribe respectively.
2.if you do not want to use prism then use an event to  fire and subscribe that event in another viewmodel where you want to subscribe the event.
Example:
use the following code at that first viewmodel which will trigger with change of the Property IsPopupOpen

```
public event MyHandler Tick;
        public EventArgs e = null;
        public delegate void MyHandler(ViewModelBase m, EventArgs e);
        MenuItemViewModel menuVM = new MenuItemViewModel();
        UpperWorkstationViewModel UpperVM = new UpperWorkstationViewModel();
        public bool _isPopupOpen = true;
        public virtual bool IsPopupOpen
        {
            get { return _isPopupOpen; }
            set
            {
                _isPopupOpen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsPopupOpen");
                menuVM.Subscribe(this);
                UpperVM.Subscribe(this);
                if (Tick != null)
                { Tick(this, e); }

                //this.SomeEvent.Invoke(IsPopupOpen);                
            }
        }
```

Now the above code will fire the event and to subscribe the event  paste the following code in any viewmodel. I have tried this code with 2 viewmodels and it is working for 2 separate viewmodel (MenuItemViewModel and UpperWorkstationViewModel )

```
public void Subscribe(MainWindowViewModel m)
        {
            m.Tick += new MainWindowViewModel.MyHandler(HeardIt);
        }
        private void HeardIt(ViewModelBase m, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (m != null)
            {
                if ((bool)(((UI.Viewmodel.MainWindowViewModel)m).IsPopupOpen))
                    IsUpperWSUsrCtlVisible = false;
                else
                    IsUpperWSUsrCtlVisible = true;
            }
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();

            //_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind,
            //        new DispatcherOperationCallback(ScheduleTransferOperation),
            //        null);
        }
```

now run the code and you will find the event will fire in all viewmodel where ever you will put the above code snippet .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use an event.  When `IsPopupOpen` changes have it invoke an event that `ViewModelB` and `ViewModelC` subscribe to.  Have this event pass a value so it can be used in your `IsUserCtlVisible` property.

```
public class ViewModelA
{  
  public event action<bool> SomeEvent;
    //invoke event somewhere 
    SomeEvent.Invoke(/*some bool argument */)
}

public class ViewModelB
{
    public bool IsUserCtlVisible { get; set; }
    public ViewModelB()
    {
        MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel();

        mvm.SomeEvent += (arg) => { IsUserCtlVisible = arg; };
    }
}
```

This is just a simple way to demonstrate the principal.  You can do this in a much cleaner way using `dependency injection` or the `prism event aggregator`.

Comment: If these are view models then they should be doing property change notification, in which case there already is an event: PropertyChanged. That's what it's for!